# Localhost Connection in Different OS

Tags: php, sql-server

I have two operating systems installed on my computer. Mac and Windows. Currently i'm developing web based application using php, xampp, and sql server 2008.

I installed local server (xampp) on MAC os, and the database engine (sql server 2008) on Windows 2008.

How can I connect my xampp to the database in different OS?

Thank in advanced.

Comment: Don't have much knowledge on multi os computers, but I believe that in order to use xampp you would need to have your mac os booted up, and in order to use sql server you would need to have windows booted up. If this is correct, you would need some type of virtualization software, to boot both os at the same time. After that it should be as simple as setting up configs and connections.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are able to boot them simulatinously, the only thing you may need to do is to port forward your router using your db port.

You don't need to do some kind of xampp modification to connect to your database. Xampp is a single workstation solution for Apache, MySQL, php bundle. You are able to use any of them in collaboration with any other outer resource.

You may want to configure your phpmyadmin to connect your new db. Necessary config file is located here: `/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`